# Email send using app password - Username and Password not accepted?

Tags: django, smtp, gmail

I can't figure out why I can't send email in `Django`.

I've enabled 2-step verification and generated App Password for this connection.

But `Gmail` smtp returns:

```
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials q29sm16257362qtc.10 - gsmtp')
```

I thought that using `App Password` will not cause such errors.

EDIT:

The email uses a custom domain but I guess this is not a problem. I think that `smtp.gmail.com` should work.

I haven't allowed less secured apps since I think it is not needed with App Password.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with two-factor authentication and allowed less secured apps. It is necessary to use App password ! there is still one last feature to activate:  https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

If you have a Gsuite domain click on this link : https://admin.google.com/ac/security/lsa  and "Allow users to manage their access to less secure applications"